# Passar variável de activity para função javascript no webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Estou tentando passar uma variável que está no SearchView na toolbar de uma activity para uma função javascript de uma página html carregada no webview, mas não estou conseguindo.

Faz dois dias que estou pesquisando a respeito e todos os exemplos que encontrei não funcionaram. Estou utilizando **sdkversion 16** no meu projeto de testes e os aparelhos nos quais serão direcionados o app são da versão 16 e superior.

Código do meu webview:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

WebClient:

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/error.html");
    }
}
```

SearchView:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    buscaString(query);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return true;
}

public void buscaString(String s){
    //Solução utilizada
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:texto('"+s+"')");

}
```

Função javascript:

```
<head>
<script>
  function texto(val){
    var $context = $(".container");

    $context.removeHighlight();
    $context.highlight(val);    
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Resolvi a questão utilizando `webView.loadUrl("javascript:texto('"+s+"')");`. Agradeço a todos que tentaram ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro defina uma classe com a anotação `@JavascriptInterface` nos métodos.

```
public class JsHelper {
    private int attr1;
    private int attr2;

    @JavascriptInterface
    public int getAttr1() {
        return attr1;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setAttr1(int attr1) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public int getAttr2() {
        return attr2;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setAttr2(int attr2) {
        this.attr2 = attr2;
    }
}
```

Crie uma instância dessa classe e passe para a WebView:

```
JsHelper helper = new JsHelper();
helper.setAttr1(2);
helper.setAttr2(0);

webView.addJavascriptInterface(javascript, "Android");
```

Dentro do webView, você pode acessar os atributos dessa instancia da seguinte forma:

```
console.log(Android.getAttr1());
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não funcionou comigo.

Comment: Edita sua resposta lá com o que você tentou agora. Talvez seja coisa boba.

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta com as alterações. Removi também o alert porque não funcionava no webview e modifiquei a função javascript. Mas mesmo assim ainda não funcionou.

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de `webView.addJavascriptInterface(javascript, "Android");`

Comment: Não esqueci, apenas troquei o "javascript" contido no seu exemlpo por helper, que é o objeto `webView.addJavascriptInterface(helper, "Android");`